how to validate OneToOne unidirectional mapped entities using annotations in spring boot
I am having two entity classes (TrainingCenter, Address) and I mapped them using @OneToOne annotation and wants to validate using @NotEmpty, @NotBlank etc annotations. but when I used validating annotations and trying to send blank data (Json Format) it shows Internal Server Error with code 500. Please help me as soon as possible Its really important. My time is running out.
TrainingCenter.java class
@Entity
@Table(name = "TrainingCenters")
public class TrainingCenter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "center_id")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 40, message = "CenterName must be maximum of 40 characters !!")
    private String centerName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 12, min = 12, message = "CenterCode must be exactly 12 character alphanumeric !!")
    private String centerCode;

    @Digits(integer = Integer.MAX_VALUE, fraction = 0, message = "Student capacity must contain only digits")
    private long studentCapacity;

    private List<String> coursesOffered;
    
    private String createdOn;
    
    @PrePersist
    private void onCreated() {
        createdOn = Long.toString(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
    }
    
    @Email(message = "Please enter a valid Email !!")
    private String contactEmail;

    @ValidPhoneNumber(message = "Invalid phone number. Phone number must have exact 10 digits.")
    private long contactPhone;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
}
}

Address.java Class
@Entity
public class Address {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int addressId;
    @NotBlank(message = "Detailed address should not be empty")
    private String detailedAddress;
    @NotBlank(message = "City should not be empty")
    private String city;
    @NotBlank(message = "State should not be empty")
    private String state;
    @Digits(integer=Integer.MAX_VALUE, fraction = 0, message = "Pincode must contain only digits")
    private long pincode;



Hi there. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information about asking questions.
